# Ubuntu 21.10 with Samba AD unable to create domain trust account

Tags: active-directory, domain, samba4, trust-relationship, mitkerberos

I am trying to add domain trust account for additional kerberos5 (MIT) domain
in Samba AD DC with command:

net rpc trustdom add <domain_name> 
-UAdministrator%<administrator_password>

What happens is that the account is created into Samba ldap database and I can
see it in Windows 11 machine.

the command gives an error message:

Could not set trust account password: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED

with command pdbedit -Lw <account_name>$ i see:

<account_name>$:3000052:NO
PASSWORDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:2D2C9A3DC21D9CAFD008D1232D77B9D0:[NDU
]:LCT-6207FF7A:

the [NDU    ] should be [I ] according to Samba Wiki documentation.

My version of samba is: Version 4.13.17-Ubuntu

There is nothing on logs I could see of related to this incident. How
should I debug this?

--
Sami Hulkko

Answer (score 0):

In recent samba versions the possibility to add Kerberos5 to kerberos5 trust one-way or two-way has not been implemented yet. There is only possibility to add Samba to Samba trust type.
net rpc trustdom add command only supports Domain trust type while Realm trust only has possibility to add it tools like FreeIpa.
Documentation of this trust feature is somewhat stub:
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Active_Directory_Trusts states only Domain to Domain trusts are the only trust types that are possible at this moment. Adding an kerberos5-Kerberos5 key based trust is not implemented though in both MIT5 and Heimdal kerberos5 systems adding trust key is a trivial task.